# rsync between two directories

Tags: rsync, command-line

Currently I use

```
rsync -avh --stats --progress dir1(source)say dir2(destination) ...
```

say I have 10 files in `dir1` and I have copied using the above command to `dir2` all 10 files.

Say now I have added another 5 files to `dir1` and I want only the new 5 files and any updates to get copied to `dir2` when I run `rsync` again. Can I use the above command and switches or should I modify it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, the same command used to copy a bounce of files with rsync could be used unmodified to update the destination directory every time the source directory change.

But the two directories do not become identical, because files deleted on the source are not deleted on the destination, if you don't ask explicitly for that. If you want that you would have to use additionally the parameter `--delete`.

Comment: I'd also add the -u flag to "skip files that are newer on the receiver".

Comment: now i have modified my rysnc as rsync -avh --progress --delete --stats --exclude-from=exclude.home  dir1(source)  dir2(destination)